# Convert string coordinates to geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, geography

I have string coordinates in my table but I want to do some geographical functionalities, So I need first to convert this string value to geography.like this:

```
geography::STGeomFromText('POINT([location])', 4326).MakeValid().STDistance(@p)
```

but for sure this code didn't work as it needs here point not string coordinates.

The full code:

```
geography::STGeomFromText('POINT([location])', 4326).MakeValid().STDistance(@p);

DECLARE @p geography;  
            SET @p = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT({$Lon} {$Lat})', 4326);
            Select TOP 1 id, location from branches where {$location} <= {$this->radius} order by {$location}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to provide a perfect solution without seeing how the code is interporlating the variables, but SQL could be having issues recognizing your long/lat as strings with the `STGeomFromText` method.

Could you try something like this:

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST([$Long] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([$Lat] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
```

Or more succinctly:

```
SELECT geography::Point([$Lat], [$Long], 4326)
```

Comment: I have no LAT and LNG from the beginning I just have a string location like this '315100,425201', I could do it if the location split to LAT and LNG

Comment: Got it, yeah in that case you can just split the string first: 
```DECLARE @coordinates VARCHAR(MAX) = '38, 78'
DECLARE @lat VARCHAR(MAX) = LEFT(@coordinates, CHARINDEX(', ', @coordinates) - 1)
DECLARE @long VARCHAR(MAX) = RIGHT(@coordinates, LEN(@coordinates) - CHARINDEX(',', @coordinates) - 1)

SELECT geography::Point(@lat, @long, 4326)```